# How to Parse multi inner child elements in XML using SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I'm unable to parse the following XML. Since child node `<plmn></plmn>` has multiple entries, I'm unable to read all the values:

```
<root>
    <EnbProfile>
        <Name>H1K-SAM_untag</Name>
        <Hardware>armony1000</Hardware>
        <PlmnList>
          <Plmn>
            <Mcc>312</Mcc>
            <Mnc>198</Mnc>
          </Plmn>
          <Plmn>
            <Mcc>389</Mcc>
            <Mnc>156</Mnc>
          </Plmn>
        </PlmnList>
    </EnbProfile>
    <EnbProfile>
        <Name>SAM_untag</Name>
        <Hardware>Armony1001</Hardware>
        <PlmnList>
          <Plmn>
            <Mcc>310</Mcc>
            <Mnc>120</Mnc>
          </Plmn>
          <Plmn>
            <Mcc>312</Mcc>
            <Mnc>190</Mnc>
          </Plmn>
        </PlmnList>
    </EnbProfile>
</root>
```

I'm new to the SAX parsing. Can anyone help me resolve this issue. I want to read all parents and multiple child nodes.

Comment: Recommend using [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html) instead of SAX. So much easier to use, with similar small memory footprint.

Comment: It is normal for xml to have duplicates. what have you coded yet ?

Comment: <PlmnList> contains multiple <Plmn> and also Mcc & Mnc values are present at each child nodes.  How SAX parse will differentiate between nodes.

Comment: sax is sequential. even two nodes with the same path are differents: there is the first to be parsed, then there is the second. No other differences. With DOM, it is almost the same thing: with the path, you get two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser; 
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory; import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLParserSAX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
            saxParser.parse(new File("D:/Projects/AadhaarOfflineVerification/app/src/main/assets/data.xml"), handler);
            List<MyHandler.Data> dataList=handler.getDataList();
            for (MyHandler.Data data:dataList) {
                System.out.println("Data "+data);
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the Main class, and I'm attaching the Handler class below

Comment: Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Also add comment line in answer itself. Avoid explaining answer on comment section.

Answer (score 0):

> import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;
>
> import org.xml.sax.Attributes; import org.xml.sax.SAXException; import
>   org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
>
> public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
>
> ```
> private StringBuilder data = null;
>
> public List<Data> getDataList() {
>     return dataList;
> }
>
> private List<Data> dataList=null;
> private List<String> mccList=null;
> private List<String> mncList=null;
> private Data dataClass=null;
>
> boolean bNames=false;
> boolean bHardwares=false;
> boolean bMcc=false;
> boolean bMnc=false;
>
> @Override
> public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
>
>
>     if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {
>
>         bNames=true;
>         dataClass=new Data();
>         if (dataList==null) {
>
>             dataList=new ArrayList<>();
>         }
>     }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Hardware")) {
>
>         bHardwares=true;
>     }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mcc")) {
>         bMcc=true;
>
>         if (mccList==null) {
>             mccList=new ArrayList<>();
>         }
>     }else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mnc")) {
>         bMnc=true;
>         if (mncList==null) {
>             mncList=new ArrayList<>();
>         }
>     }
>
>     data = new StringBuilder();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
>
>
>     if (bNames) {
>         dataClass.setNames(data.toString());
>         bNames=false;
>     }else if (bHardwares) {
>         dataClass.setHardwares(data.toString());
>         bHardwares=false;
>     }else if (bMcc) {
>         mccList.add(data.toString());
>         bMcc=false;
>     }else if (bMnc) {
>         mncList.add(data.toString());
>         bMnc=false;
>     }
>
>     if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Plmn")) {
>         dataClass.setMccList(mccList);
>         dataClass.setMncList(mncList);
>     }
>
>     if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {
>
>         dataList.add(dataClass);
>     }
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
>     data.append(new String(ch, start, length));
> }
>
>
> class Data {
>
>     private String names;
>     private String hardwares;
>
>     private List<String> mccList;
>     private List<String> mncList;
>
>     public String getNames() {
>         return names;
>     }
>
>     public void setNames(String names) {
>         this.names = names;
>     }
>
>     public String getHardwares() {
>         return hardwares;
>     }
>
>     public void setHardwares(String hardwares) {
>         this.hardwares = hardwares;
>     }
>
>     public List<String> getMccList() {
>         return mccList;
>     }
>
>     public void setMccList(List<String> mccList) {
>         this.mccList = mccList;
>     }
>
>     public List<String> getMncList() {
>         return mncList;
>     }
>
>     public void setMncList(List<String> mncList) {
>         this.mncList = mncList;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public String toString() {
>         return "Data:: Name="+this.names+" Hardware="+this.hardwares+" Mcc List="+mccList.toString()+" Mnc
> ```
>
> List="+mncList.toString();
>           }
>       } }

Comment: This is the Handler class which extends the "org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler" class.Run both XMLParserSAX  and MyHandler class,and replace   "D:/Projects/AadhaarOfflineVerification/app/src/main/assets/data.xml"  this path with the xml file path in your system.